# Using HTML drop menu to generate forms

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site built. When a user selects an option from a dropdown menu, I want them to then be able to hit a submit button to open up a PDF stored on a server (I have the logistics behind this done already).

This is entirely internal. Clients will open the site, which will submit the request to the server, and pull files from the server.

I have been able to create HTML to have IE prompt a user to open the PDF from the server on their computer. Now I need to figure out how to implement it in this. (the names I use for option values has been changed for privacy reasons)

```
<form style="text-align:center;>
<form action="">
<select name="hidden">
<option value="v1">v1</option>
<option value="v2">v2</option>
<option value="v3">v3</option>
<option value="v4">v4</option>
<option value="v5">v5</option>
<option value="v6">v6</option>
</select>
```

The code I used to prompt a user to open a file that is stored on a local server is:

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<a href="file://R:/Users/User_name/Folder/File_Name">Click Me</a>
</body>
<html>
```

My brain is fried and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to combine the two.

(summary: Drop list that, when an option is selected and the user hits a submit button, runs the bottom code I provided to open up files stored on the server)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="hidden" onchange="openFile();">
   <option value="v1">v1</option>
   <option value="v2">v2</option>
   ...
</select>

<script>
function openFile() {
    // do selection logic
    window.location.href = "PDF_LOCATION.pdf";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed something in my question. I want a submit button to do the actual requesting of the .pdf's

Comment: Can your pdf file be requested by URL? If so the code should work fine. You can do the selection criteria in the onchange handler above